# The chef-client command on node gives error 307 "Temporarily Moved for Domain Name Expansion"

Tags: chef-infra

When i try to run chef-client command on  a node in chef i get the " 307 "Temporarily Moved for Domain Name Expansion" " error. How to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You have `--bootstrap-proxy` with HTTPS but on port 80. That sounds unusual. If that is correct for some reason I would check the value of your `chef_server_url` in the Knife config against what your Chef admin tells you it should be.

Comment: I am getting this error even when i  run chef-client

Answer (score 0):

chef_server_url in client.rb might not have host name with complete domain name. Check if that is a valid accessible hostname.

Comment: I am getting this error even when i do chef-client on node. ANd yes the url is valid accessible hostname only.@Amod Pandey

Comment: Does this work for you 'telnet <chef_server_url> 443' from that node